# submit form not storing data to database

Tags: php, laravel

So i was trying to make a posting form using `ckeditor` and post it to database, and then try to display it in the same view, but after i submit the form i don't see anything in my database table so clearly it's not even storing to database, is there any mistakes in my controller or view ?

this is my GuestbookController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Guestbook;

class GuestbookController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $guestbooks = Guestbook::get();
        return view('post.post_textarea',[
            'guestbooks' => $guestbooks,
        ]);
    }

    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        Guestbook::create([
            'name' => $request->name,
            'message' => $request->message
        ]);
        return redirect()->back();
    }
}
```

this is my routes

```
Route::get('/posting','GuestbookController@index')->name('guestbook');
Route::post('/posting','GuestbookController@store')->name('guestbook.store');
```

this is my model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Guestbook extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['name', 'message'];
}
```

and this is my view

```
<section class="games-single-page">
        <div class="container">
            @foreach ($guestbooks as $guestbook)
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <label>mike</label>
                    <h3>{{ $guestbok->name }}</h3>
                    {!! $guestbook->message !!}
                </div>
            </div>
            @endforeach
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <form action="/posting" method "POST">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label style="color: black;" >Title</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label style="color: black;" >Your Input</label>
                            <br>
                                <textarea class="form-control" name="message" id="" rows="10"></textarea>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value"Send">  
                        </div>                     
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

Comment: Did you check if you're getting request['message'] in store. What is the Data Types for message field?

Comment: Does it enter the correct controller method? Inside your `store()` method, what is `dd($request);`? Have you made a table for the guestbook? Have you enabled error-reporting?

Comment: @jones the data types for message was text, @Qirel i did ```dd($request);```  but i didn't get anything it only goes back to the original page , but the url is showing the data i entered

Comment: Ahh! So, the issue is that you are not actually sending over POST, you're sending over GET - because you have a typo in your form, `method "POST"` should be `method="POST"`. Try that and see what happens ;-)

Comment: may be you forgot to send request on post with csrf field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot an equal sign '=' and a csrf field. try the answer.

```
<form action="/posting" method="POST">
{{csrf_field()}}
```

Comment: Typo-questions should be closed, and not answered - as they are considered off-topic for this platform.

Comment: Should I remove the answer and link the similar question?

Comment: The missing the equal sign is a typo, and there's a flag to close it as such. :-) If there are similar questions, you can flag it as a duplicate if you don't have anything extra to add.

Comment: @hasan05 i tried it but it shows object not found, and i checked the database again still shows nothing

Comment: ow a forgot that the action doesn't go anywhere so it says object not found , when i delete it it works !!! thanks @hasan05